# Count the number of occurences in each bucket Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, count, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

This might be difficult to explain. But Im trying to write a redshift sql query where I have want the count of organizations that fall into different market buckets. There are 50 markets. For example company x can be only be found in 1 market and company y can be found in 3 markets. I want to preface that I have over 10,000 companies to fit into these buckets. So ideally it would be more like, hypothetically 500 companies are found in 3 markets or 7 companies are found in 50 markets.

The table would like

| Market Bucket | Org Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Markets | 3 |
| 2 Markets | 1 |
| 3 Markets | 0 |

`select count(distinct case when enterprise_account = true and (market_name  then organization_id end) as "1 Market" from organization_facts`

I was trying to formulate the query from above but I got confused on how to effectively formulate the query

Organization Facts

| Market Name | Org ID | Org Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New York | 15683 | Company x |
| Orlando | 38478 | Company y |
| Twin Cities | 2738 | Company z |
| Twin Cities | 15683 | Company x |
| Detroit | 99 | Company xy |

Comment: Please update your question to show sample data from the `organization_facts` table (used for input) that would produce the results you have shown.

Comment: Where is the `enterprise_account` column, or is that not relevant?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thats not relevant

Answer (score 0):

You would need a sub-query that retrieves the number of markets per company, and an outer query that summarises into a count of markets.

Something like:

```sql
with markets as (
  select
    org_name,
    count(distinct market_name) as market_count
  from organization_facts
)

select
  market_count,
  count(*) as org_count
from markets
group by market_count
order by market_count
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can do this with two levels of aggregation. Assuming that `org_id` represents a company in your dataset:

```
select cnt_markets, count(*) cnt_org_id
from (select count(*) cnt_markets from organization_facts group by org_id) t
group by cnt_markets
```

The subquery counts the number of markets per company. I assumed no duplicate `(ord_id, market_name)` tuples in the table ; if that's not the case, then you need `count(distinct market_name)` instead of `count(*)` in that spot.

Then, the outer query just counts how many times each market count occurs in the subquery, which yields the result that you want.

Note that I left apart the `enterprise_account` column ,that appears in your query but not in your data.